# Multiple dynamic Tax Query - pass taxonomy argument from array

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, tax-query

I need to make a multiple dynamic tax query

```
 $args['tax_query'] = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomies,

                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $attributes,
                'operator' => 'IN',
            )

        );
```

As reported on codex refence https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/

So, how can I set the tax query args from two arrays: one for terms and one for taxonomies?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you want to query. Do you want posts that have jazz, improv etc in either genre *or* dance? Or in genre *and* dance? Do the posts need to have the same term in both taxonomies? You will need to elaborate on what you want.

Comment: No, the second code is the abstract of the codex reference I quoted. Do you think it creates confusion? The question is "how can I set the tax query args from two arrays?" One for terms and one for taxonomies I got two arrays from a form, I'm working on an ajax filter. I need to create a tax query with multiple taxonomies and relatives terms.